# How to configure Webpack 2.2.1? Error ... configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have installed webpack and webpack-dev-server for my React.js app and am having trouble with configuring the webpack.base.js file.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

var config = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8888/',
    path: './build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_componenets)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: 'transform-runtime',
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        "style-loader",
        "css-loader"
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }, {
      // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
          name: '/resources/images/[name].[ext]',
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      "node_modules"
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      $prefetch: 'src/prefetch',
      $fetchData: 'src/fetchData',
      $language: 'src/text/lang',
      $beforeEnter: 'src/beforeEnter',
      $components: 'src/temp',
      $svg: 'src/svg/index',
      $style: 'scss',
      $containers: 'src/containers',
      $actions: 'src/actions',
      $util: 'src/util',
      $reducers: 'src/reducers',
      $themes: 'src/theme',
      $auth: 'src/auth',
      $home: 'src/',
      $resources: 'resources',
      $navbarSelected: 'resources/images/navbar/selected',
      $navbarUnselected: 'resources/images/navbar/unselected',
      $plugins: 'src/plugins',
      $vendor: 'vendor',
      $test: 'tests',
      $testStore: 'tests/stores'
    },
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'promise-polyfill',
      fetch: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

However, when I run webpack-dev-server in the root of my directory I'm getting the following error.

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string] | function
   The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry should be an object.
    * configuration.entry should be a string.
    * configuration.entry should NOT have duplicate items (items ## 1 and 3 are identical) ({
        "keyword": "uniqueItems",
        "dataPath": ".entry",
        "schemaPath": "#/definitions/common.nonEmptyArrayOfUniqueStringValues/uniqueItems",
        "params": {
          "i": 3,
          "j": 1
        },
        "message": "should NOT have duplicate items (items ## 1 and 3 are identical)",
        "schema": true,
        "parentSchema": {
          "items": {
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 1,
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "data": [
          "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8888",
          "webpack/hot/dev-server",
          "/Users/tormod/Desktop/smartzer/panda/ReactFiles/editor/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8888",
          "webpack/hot/dev-server",
          "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888",
          "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
          "./index.jsx"
        ]
      }).
      [non-empty string]
    * configuration.entry should be an instance of function
      function returning an entry object or a promise..
```

This is making no sense to me as there are no duplicates in config.entry. Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this error.

Verisons

webpack-dev-server 2.4.1

webpack 2.2.1

Comment: Could you change the output publicPath in your config to '/' and see if it works properly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this but getting the same error, what was your thinking?

Comment: How are you running `webpack-dev-server`? It looks like there is a conflict between the locally and globally installed package, although it shouldn't include both. Try creating a script in `package.json`: `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.base.js"` and run it with `npm run dev`. If that still gives you the error you could try to remove the globally installed one with `npm uninstall -g webpack-dev-server`.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when I moved from 1.14 to 2.5 with an array similar to yours.  What solved it for me was removing 'webpack/hot/dev-server' from the array.  Everything still behaved the same even with that removed as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [latest docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/), the entry path needs to be either a string or an object.

so it should be somethings like this

```
entry: `/index.jsx`
```

or

```
entry: 
   {
          dev-server: 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888',
          hot: 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
          index: '/index.jsx',
    }
```

I would probably just include the `index.jsx` file as the entry and move the `webpack-dev-server` config options as a separate key in the `webpack.config.js` file. There are quite a couple of ways you [accomplish this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, still the same error though. I have seen in the docs where they use the `entry: [ 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', '/index.jsx' ]`

Comment: this works for me (taken from create-react-app):
`entry: [
    require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    './src/index.js'
  ]`